# sorting list of tuples by arbitrary key

Tags: python

```
order = ['w','x','a','z']
[(object,'a'),(object,'x'),(object,'z'),(object,'a'),(object,'w')]
```

How do I sort the above list of tuples by the second element according the the key list provided by 'order'?

UPDATE on 11/18/13:

I found a much better approach to a variation of this question where the keys are certain to be unique, detailed in this question: [Python: using a dict to speed sorting of a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059427/python-using-a-dict-to-speed-sorting-of-a-list-of-tuples).

My above question doesn't quite apply because the give list of tuples has two tuples with the key value of `'a'`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are expecting the result to look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sorted`, and give as the `key` a function that returns the index of the second value of each tuple in the `order` list.

```
>>> sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: order.index(x[1]))

[('object', 'w'), ('object', 'x'), ('object', 'a'), ('object', 'a'), ('object', 'z')]
```

Beware, this fails whenever a value from the tuples is not present within the `order` list.

**Edit:**

In order to be a little more secure, you could use :

```
sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: x[1] in order and order.index(x[1]) or len(order)+1)
```

This will put all entries with a key that is missing from `order` list at the end of the resulting list.

Comment: That last edit was very helpful because now I can let the sort fail in a very elegant way. Thanks!