# Python: using a dict to speed sorting of a list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

For some reason, I keep having 'how do I sort this list of tuples' questions. (A prior question of mine: [sorting list of tuples by arbitrary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408919/sorting-list-of-tuples-by-arbitrary-key)).

Here is some arbitrary raw input:

```
number_of = 3  # or whatever
tuple_list = [(n, 'a', 'b', 'c') for n in xrange(number_of)]  # [(0, 'a', 'b', 'c')...]
ordering_list = random.sample(range(number_of), number_of)  # e.g. [1, 0, 2]
```

Sorting `tuple_list` by `ordering_list` using sorted:

```
ordered = sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda t: ordering_list.index(t[0]))
# ordered = [(1, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (0, 'a', 'b', 'c'), (2, 'a', 'b', 'c')]
```

I have a slightly awkward approach which seems to be much faster, especially as the number of elements in the `tuple_list` grows. I create a dictionary, breaking the `tuple` into `(tuple[0], tuple[1:])` items inside dictionary `list_dict`. I retrieve the dictionary item using `ordering_list` as keys, and then re-assemble the sequence of `(tuple[0], tuple[1:])` into a list of tuples, using an idiom I'm still trying to wrap my head around completely: `zip(*[iter(_list)] * x)` where `x` is the length of each tuple composed of items from `_list`. So my question is: is there a version of this approach which is manages the disassemble - reassemble part of the code better?

```
def gen_key_then_values(key_list, list_dict):
    for key in key_list:
        values = list_dict[key]
        yield key

        for n in values:
            yield n

list_dict = {t[0]: t[1:] for t in tuple_list}
ordered = zip(*[gen_key_then_values(ordering_list, list_dict)] * 4)
```

NOTE BETTER CODE, using an obvious comment from Steve Jessop below:

```
list_dict = {t[0]: t for t in tuple_list}
ordered = [list_dict[k] for k in ordering_list]
```

My actual project code still requires assembling a tuple for each `(k, ['a', 'b' ...])` item retrieved from the `list_dict` but there was no reason for me to include that part of the code here.

Comment: can you fix indexing typo for `ordered`: `ordered = sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda t: ordering_list[t[0]])` use brackets

Comment: @MarkMikofski Thanks. The key is based on the index value, and I omitted `index` in the code, which has been corrected to read: `key=lambda t: ordering_list.index(t[0])`

Comment: @Cole: ah, that's not just a typo, that's a very different thing entirely.  `ordering_list.index(t[0])` has to scan through `ordering_list` to find `t[0]`, a linear operation, again and again (for each element of `tuple_list`).  That will be very slow.

Comment: `.index` is evil. It's nearly always better to be using a `dict` (ie unless the number of calls to `.index` is very small)

Comment: @gnibbler Your point is one of the reasons I wanted to get this question up on stackoverflow because I was using .index() based on other questions that are readily google-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the elements of `tuple_list` apart in the dictionary doesn't really gain you anything and requires creating a bunch more tuples for the values. All you're doing is looking up elements in the list according to their first element, so it's probably not worth actually splitting them:

```
list_dict = { t[0] : t for t in tuple_list }
```

Note that this only works if the first element is unique, but then the `ordering_list` only makes sense if the first element is unique, so that's probably OK.

`zip(*[iter(_list)] * 4)` is just a way of grouping `_list` into fours, so give it a suitable name and you won't have to worry about it:

```
def fixed_size_groups(n, iterable):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)
```

But all things considered you don't actually need it anyway:

```
ordered = list(list_dict[val] for val in ordering_list)
```

The reason your first code is slow, is that `ordering_list.index` is slow -- it searches through the `ordering_list` for `t[0]`, and it does this once for each `t`. So in total it does `(number_of ** 2) / 2` inspections of a list element.

Comment: Thanks, and of course! (and I feel a little silly) `{t[0]: t for t in tuple list}` eliminated the need for a good chunk of the code.

Comment: One of the reasons I asked this question is that I had been using  `sorted()` to solve for sorting a list based on an arbitrary sequence of unique values. This choice was influenced by earlier stackoverflow questions, including mine. So I want to suggest a different approach for others, and make sure the best version of the different approach was gather here. To that end, your comment is very helpful.